# Extension Method and Razor Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, extension-methods, webmatrix

I have defined an extension method in app_code like below.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string Hi(this object obj)
    {
        return "hi";
    }
}
```

In the razor page, anything can say Hi :)

```
@Html.Hi();
@Request.Hi();   
@this.Hi();
```

But `@Hi()` doesn't work. Is there a way to make `@Hi()` work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# only allows you to call extension methods qualified by an object instance.
If you have an extension method that extends your type, you can't call it "directly"; you need to write `this.ExtensionMethod()`.

The only way to do what you're asking for is to make a class which inherits `WebPage` (or `WebViewPage` for MVC views) and change your Razor page to inherit that class (using the `@inherits` directive)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can call just @Hi(). Pretty sure is has to be @this.Hi()

Answer (score 0):

Just like a normal scenario you have to include it in a using. the razor syntaz is

```
@using Namespace.Namespace
```