# Extending System.Web.WebPage without 'this'

Tags: c#

I am trying to extend the `System.Web.WebPage` class to expose a method called `RenderZone`:

```
using System.Web.WebPages;

public static class WebPageExtensions
{
    public static HelperResult RenderZone(this WebPage webPage, int zone) {
    return webPage.RenderPage("~/_RenderWidgets.cshtml", new {ZoneId = zone});
    }
}
```

This works, but in order to call the extension method within a page file (.cshtml), I have to prefix the method call with `this` e.g.

```
@this.RenderZone(1)
```

Is there a way to extend the WebPage type so that I can leave out the `this` in a similar way to calling RenderPage from within the cshtml file?

```
@RenderPage("~/_PageToRender.cshtml")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative would be to create a new class that your page derives from instead of `WebPage`.  For example:

```
public class WebPagePlus : WebPage
{
    public HelperResult RenderZone(int zone) {
       return this.RenderPage("~/_RenderWidgets.cshtml", new {ZoneId = zone});
    }
}
```

Then derive from it instead of WebPage

```
public class MyWebPage : WebPagePlus // WebPage
{
//...
}
```

Comment: You could also use the `@inherits` of the Razor view to use `WebPagePlus`. Ref - [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5011715/326543)