# Is there any way add extension methods to razor PageModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Working on .Net core razor page. I want share some common methods among RazorPages (ex: HomeModel.cs).

Wrote below extension method

```
public static class PageModelExtension
{
    public static string RemoteIpAddress(this PageModel pageModel)
    {
        return pageModel.Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
    }
}
```

Not sure how to access in Page Model like below.

```
public class HomeModel : PageModel
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        // .... some code
        var ip = this.RemoteIpAddress(); // I want to use 'RemoteIpAddress' here

        return Page();
    }
}
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/5011715/9020340

Answer (score 3):

You use the *ViewImports* file to bring a namespace into scope in all Razor Pages.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WebApplication1.Extensions
{
    public static class PageModelExtension
    {
        public static string RemoteIpAddress(this PageModel pageModel)
        {
            return pageModel.Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the ViewImports file:

```
@using WebApplication1.Extensions
```

Then in your .cshtml file:

```
@{
    var ip = this.RemoteIpAddress();
}
```

If you want to access it in the PageModel class itself, add a `using` directive for the namespace containing your extension method and then use `this.RemoteIpAddress()`

More [about the ViewImports file in Razor Pages here](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/files/viewimports)

Comment: import is there

Comment: @Ravi Added some updates to the answer. Is there still a problem?

Comment: I have to use it in PageModel like in public class LoginModel : PageModel and unable to access extension methods in LoginModel class

Comment: You need to edit your existing question to show the code you are trying to use and explain what errors you are getting.

Comment: I have have updated the question with more details. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace MyDll.MyNamespace
{
    public static class PageModelExtension
    {
        public static string RemoteIpAddress(this PageModel pageModel)
        {
            return pageModel.Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Go to the View's web.config and add the namespace to the path `system.web/pages/namespaces`:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <pages>
        <namespaces>
             ....
            <add namespace="MyDll.MyNamespace" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

Comment: This will work in an ASP.NET MVC 5 application, but not in a .NET Core Razor Pages application.